# Exact $(1-\alpha)100\%$ confidence interval for $\theta$ in $\operatorname{Gamma}(4, \frac{1}{\theta})$

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation, confidence-interval, gamma-distribution, chi-squared

I am trying to solve the following problem for exercise purposes:

> Let $ X_1, ..., X_n $ be independent and identically distributed
>   random variables with the probability density function:
>
> $$ f(x\mid \theta) = \frac{x^3e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}}{6\theta^4} $$ where $x >
> 0$ and $\theta > 0$.
>
> Assuming that we know that quantiles from the chi-square distribution can be computed exactly, please construct an exact $(1-\alpha)100\%$ confidence interval for $\theta$.

I have computed the Maximum Likelihood Estimator of $\theta$ to be $\hat{\theta} = \frac{\bar{X}}{4}$.

I also observed that based on the pdf $f(x\mid \theta)$, $X_i \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(4, \frac{1}{\theta})$ where 4 is the shape and $\frac{1}{\theta}$ is the $\textbf{rate}$ of the gamma distribution. Therefore, $\frac{2}{\theta}X_i \sim \chi^2_8$.

I  am stuck at this step. Could someone please advise me on how I could take it from here?

Comment: $\frac2{\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\sim \chi^2_{8n}$, which gives a pivot for constructing the confidence interval. Finding MLE is not required here.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Ah! Thanks. Solved it. My answer is $ (\frac{2 * \sum_{i=1}^n{X_i}}{\chi_{8n}^2(\frac{\alpha}{2})}, \frac{2 * \sum_{i=1}^n{X_i}}{\chi_{8n}^2(\frac{1-\alpha}{2})}) $

Comment: It should be $\chi^2_{8n}(1-\frac{\alpha}2)$ in the denominator.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes! Silly me. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: You can post an answer and accept it.